# how to set up environment variables for python

Tags: python, environment-variables

On WinXP sp2 I'd like to have a directory of modules that other python scripts will be using called "SharedPython" in the same directory as my python scripts. so, basically:

> /pythonScripts
>   /pythonScripts/SharedPython

as well as other python scripts on the same level as the SharedPython directory.

when I run

```
print sys.path
```

I get the following output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\python25.zip
C:\Python25\DLLs
C:\Python25\lib
C:\Python25\lib\plat-win
C:\Python25\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python25
C:\Python25\lib\site-packages
```

I don't know what environment variable controls this and, in fact, I don't see one that contains all these directories.
So, 
a.)how do I determine which environment variable contains this list of dirs?
and
b.)can I just add the aforementioned SharedPython dir to that list?

I've tried setting PYTHONPATH to the following: %PYTHONPATH%C:\PythonScripts\SharedPython

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the  `PYTHONPATH` env var. The dirs listed in it are prepended to `sys.path`.

The correct way to setup `PYTHONPATH` in your case is:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\PythonScripts\SharedPython
```

Note the semicolon between the second `%` and the `C:\`

Comment: I already have the python path set to this:  %PYTHONPATH%C:\PythonScripts\SharedPython  and it's still not working.

Comment: @Ramy: That doesn't look right. output PYTHONPATH with `echo %PYTHONPATH%` and see what it contains

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\ramy.abdel-azim>echo %PYTHONPATH%
%PYTHONPATH%C:\PythonScripts\SharedPython

Comment: that seems to have done it. Windows environment variables are so annoying to me.

Comment: **Tip:** You can make the change permanently by right-clicking on My Computer and selecting Properties. Select the Advanced tab in the dialog box that appears and then click on the Environment Variables button. Aanother dialog box will appear and in that you can define the PYTHONPATH variable to be what you want.

Comment: thanks, @martineau. that's how i've been updating environment variables all along.    I still have the problem of my script not finding a user defined module I've placed in the SharedPython directory (which is now part of the pythonpath).

Comment: @Ramy: In your Python script you can print out `sys.path` to make sure it's right. Also, make sure the case of the characters in the name you `import` matches that of the corresponding `.py` module file because it matters, even on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Those paths are added by the [`site`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) module; do not change this module, but rather create a batch file that adds your paths in `%PYTHONPATH%` and then runs the script.

Comment: what would the batch file look like and where would it be picked up/run? i.e. who calls the batch file?

Comment: It would contain a `SET` command to set the variable, and a call to the Python script/executable. It can be put anywhere, but somewhere in `%PATH%` would be convenient. It would be called by the user or by a shortcut.

Comment: that seems like a lot of overhead if I have to create a batch script that will update the >PATH and then call the script. i'd rather have the scheduled task call the script directly as I have for most of my other python scripts.